# Chart.js - Add gradient to bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am looking to build a chart like this

[image]

But I am not able to give the gradient colors in the y-scale for the bar chart. This is the codesandbox [URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5rwoqp8on).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447579/chart-js-add-gradient-instead-of-solid-color-implementing-solution Similar question, already answered

Comment: @Christian my question was about bar chart. For the bar chart, I was able to apply gradient horizontally, but I am unable to do it vertically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gradient **direction** (Vertically in your case) not related directly to `chart.js`, but to **HTML canvas** [createLinearGradient()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_createlineargradient.asp) Method.

**`createLinearGradient` JavaScript syntax:**

```
context.createLinearGradient(x0,y0,x1,y1);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_createlineargradient.asp

**Example of top to bottom "vertically" gradient from w3schools:**

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var my_gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 170);
my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
ctx.fillStyle = my_gradient;
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```

```html
<div>Top to bottom</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

### "One gradient"

**Docs:**

> An alternative option is to pass a CanvasPattern or CanvasGradient
>   object instead of a string colour. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#patterns-and-gradients

Same as one solid color but passing `CanvasGradient` object:

```
var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

var background_1 = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
background_1.addColorStop(0, 'red');
background_1.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
```

And set `background_1` under data

```
/* data */
var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "America"],
  datasets: [{
    /* data */
    label: "Population (millions)",
    backgroundColor: background_1,
    data: [40,60,80, 100]
  }]
};
```

### "multiple colors for bars"

Use multiple gradients objects inside backgroundColor (object1 for item-1 and so on).

```js
backgroundColor: [background_1, background_2, background_3, background_4],
```

** My code is not DRY (The best idea her is to create gradient objects by some loop throw array of data). By purpose i keep this example "simple".

```js
var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

var background_1 = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
background_1.addColorStop(0, 'red');
background_1.addColorStop(1, 'blue');

var background_2 = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
background_2.addColorStop(0, 'green');
background_2.addColorStop(1, 'orange');

var background_3 = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
background_3.addColorStop(0, 'orange');
background_3.addColorStop(1, 'purple');

var background_4 = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
background_4.addColorStop(0, 'green');
background_4.addColorStop(1, 'violet');

/* data */
var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "America"],
  datasets: [{
    /* data */
    label: "Population (millions)",
    backgroundColor: [background_1, background_2, background_3, background_4],
    data: [40,60,80, 100]
  }]
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    text: 'multiple colors for bars',
    display: true
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {

      },
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
    }]
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
  <canvas id="chart" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

Comment: This is working almost as I want, but for the first bar you gave gradient as "red" and "blue", but we can't see red color because you gave gradient for full length i.e. 600, is there any way we can give it only for the bar height so that we will be able to see red color in the bar.

Comment: "nice" issue. I thinks the best idea is to create "new" stackoverflow Q related to this issue.

Comment: @Lucifer Did you figure it out? How to make the bar show the "full" gradient? If so, can you share?

Answer (score 0):

Try to click one of the jsfiddle there, then change the chart type to 'bar'. You'll see it will work.

Yes they are all the same color, because on their example they are only using one gradient. You can create multiple gradient with different color and apply it seperately since you are using multiple rgba already, you can change it and apply specific gradient to your bar. My english is not that good i hope you get my point.

Comment: That works because there we are applying same color for each bar, but in my case, I want multiple colors for bars.