# How to create a gradient fill line chart in latest Chart JS version (3.3.2)?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am wondering how to create a gradient line chart fill in **Chart JS version 3.3.2** like this:[image]

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447579/chart-js-add-gradient-instead-of-solid-color-implementing-solution) was answered nearly 6 years ago. What is the solution in 2021 with version [3.3.2](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)?

I have tried the old solution to no avail:

*Code:*

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(224, 195, 155, 1)');   
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(100, 100, 0,0)');
        
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: gradient,
                    label: 'Numbers',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            },
            tension: 0.3
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktuefyw9/17/)

Comment: This post might help you: https://blog.vanila.io/chart-js-tutorial-how-to-make-gradient-line-chart-af145e5c92f9

Comment: @mpm that article wont help, thats about chart.js version 2 as he already pointed out that that solution does not work from the stack issue

Comment: oh, I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You where almost there, in v3 by default line charts dont fill so you will need to set `fill: true`

Example

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(224, 195, 155, 1)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(100, 100, 0,0)');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: gradient,
          label: 'Numbers',
          fill: true,
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        },
        tension: 0.3
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. You are a lifesaver

Comment: How to do this in React.js?

Comment: Make it a scriptable option in there you get the canvas

Comment: Great answer, but what if I have two datasets and I want to fill both with different background gradients? How do I create the gradient for the second dataset?

Comment: You can copy paste the code for the first gradient and put it in a variable called gradient2